# Error occurs when I import csv in table rates tab

Tags: magento2

I want to set shipping charges according to me, when I imported a csv it throws error -

> The file "/tmp/opt/lampp/temp/phpdtjPun" doesn't exist

Can  anyone help me. I am new to magento 2.1.0

[image]